# How to delete the edges while deleting the vertics in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I working on an undirected graph from a edges file, I try to delete the high degree vertices using `g.delete_vertices(107)`, but I think it works not right, for example, the whole graph has 4039 nodes and 88234 edges, the degree of the `vertex(107)` is 1045 and the `vertex(1684)` is 792 , so when I delete the nodes(107 and 1684) one by one, the edges connected to them should also be deleted, then the number of edges should be reduced to `88234-1045=87189` and `87189-791=86398`, but I obtained a strange number 87189 and 87127, I don't know what was happened.

```py
{'UserID': '107', 'degree': 1045},
{'UserID': '1684', 'degree': 792},
{'UserID': '1912', 'degree': 755},


import graph:
edges = []
#f= open('facebook_data', "r") 
with open('facebook_data.csv','rt',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f.read().splitlines()):
                u, v = [i for i in row]
                edges.append((u, v))
#print(edges)
from igraph import Graph as IGraph
g = IGraph.TupleList(edges, directed=False, vertex_name_attr='UserID', edge_attrs=None, weights=False)
print( 'number of nodes: '+ str(len(g.vs())))
print( 'number of edges: '+ str(len(g.es())))
for p in g.vs:
    print (p["UserID"],p.degree())
names = g.vs["UserID"]
g.delete_vertices(107)
len(g.es()) #calculate the number of edges
```